# Ergonomic way to define elements of dependent records in proof mode?

Tags: coq

I tend to have trouble defining elements of dependent records when I would like to define their fields in proof mode.

Consider the following simple minimal example:

```
Record foo : Type := {
  num : nat;
  num_refl : num = num
  }.

Goal foo.
Proof.
  econstructor.
  (* goal is now ?num = ?num *)
Abort.
```

I would like to be able to instantiate `?num` in proof mode since ?num stands in for expressions that generally will be difficult to write out by hand.  Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
Goal foo.
Proof.
  better_econstructor.
  (* generates two goals, nat and ?num = ?num *)
  - exact 2.
  - (* goal is now 2 = 2 *) reflexivity.
Defined.
```

Are there any approaches that mimic this style?  Right now, I define the non-dependent stuff elsewhere and then do the proofs using refine, i.e. something like

```
Definition two : nat := 2.

Goal foo.
Proof.
  refine {|
    num := two;
    num_refl := _
    |}.
  reflexivity.
Defined.
```

This works but is a bit tedious when it involves copying and pasting a lot of types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `unshelve tac` tactical. It applies `tac` and transforms every existential variable it creates into a goal.

```
Goal foo.
Proof.
  unshelve econstructor.
```

Answer (score 1):

Another more explicit solution (using ssreflect syntax here) would be to use a local lemma:

```
Goal foo.
Proof.
  have two : nat by exact: 2.
  econstructor.
  exact: (erefl two).
Qed.
```